# How to make the button moveable from right to left when broweser size changes

Tags: html

I am trying to move the third button from right to left when the browser gets small. What are the possible ways to make it moveable when the browser size changes. Specifically, I want to the third button to move from right to left when the browser size changes.

```
<!Doctype html>
 <html>
  <style>
  .btn-group button {
     background-color: #4CAF50; 
     border: 1px solid green; 
     color: white; 
     padding: 10px 24px; 
     cursor: pointer; 
     float: left; 
}

 .btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
     border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
 }
 .btn-group button:last-child{
     float:right;
     margin-right:20px;
     display:flex;
     flex-wrap:wrap;
     flex-direction:row;
   }
.btn-group:after {
     content: "";
     clear: both;
     display: table;
   }

.btn-group button:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
 }
</style>
```

```
<h1>Button Group</h1>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <button>Apple</button>
    <button>Samsung</button>
    <button>Sony</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an id for the 3rd button, for example, `<button id="Sony">Sony</button>`

Then add onresize-event to body: `<body onresize="myFunction()">`, where "myFunction()" is a function that launches on resize.

the function could be something like this, for example:

```
function reSize(){
  var button = document.getElementById('Sony');
  button.style.margin-right = "200px";
}
```

This would increase the margin-right of "Sony"-button by 200 pixels when body is resized.

Comment: In case you dont know, right-click the page and select "Inspect Element", then you can see the current properties of the elements, like margin and padding. This helps visualizing the changes you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to detect the browser window size, then, with an id added to the Sony button, apply new css to that third button to change it's position.

For example, something like:

```
      <!-- your other html here -->

    <button id="thirdBtn">Sony</button>
```

then in css:

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      #thirdBtn {
      position: relative;
      left: 80%;
   // or whatever you want, like float: right; or right: 5em; etc
   }
   }
```

Comment: hum,I am not looking for any solutions with @media query though it worked with display: flex options...